# Multibinding with Resource and DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have c#-code behind to set the title for my XAML-window:

```
this.Title = string.Concat(Business_Layer.Properties.Resources.WORD_VEHICLE_DATA_SHEET, 
" - ", 
(dataContext as Business_Layer.Windows.MainWindow).SelectedVehicle.LicenseNumber);
```

I want to achiev this in XAML directly. So I have tried:

```
<Window.Title>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
        <Binding Source="{x:Static Stringtable:Resources.WORD_VEHICLE_DATA_SHEET}"/>
        <Binding Source="{x:Static SelectedVehicle.LicenseNumber}"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</Window.Title>
```

The 'SelectedVehicle'-Property is in the DataContext. With this approach I always get errors. I have tried Path instead of source without any success..

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

My problem was the following:

```
<Binding Path="{SelectedVehicle.LicenseNumber}"/>
```

I had have the {} between the ""... Sorry for my behaviour ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second binding should be

```
<Binding Path="SelectedVehicle.LicenseNumber"/>
```

Comment: if I do it, I get the errors:

Nested types are not supported: SelectedVehicle.LicenseNumber



The type 'SelectedVehicle' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built



The tag 'SelectedVehicle.LicenseNumber' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'.

Comment: I assumed that SelectedVehicle is a property of the DataContext object, and that LicenseNumber is a property of the type of SelectedVehicle. So what is it actually?

Comment: look at my 1st post, I have edited it to show my issue.

Comment: The edit doesn't explain what SelectedVehicle and LicenseNumber are.

Comment: I have found my problem. Look at edit in 1st post. Sorry for wasting your time my friend ;)